# Загрузка файлов в несколько потоков

Tags: java, многопоточность

```
public class LoaderBean {


    protected void download(List<File> files, String path, String nThreads) {
        for (File file : files) {
            new Downloader(file.getUrl(), path, file.getName()).startDownload();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println(" ============================== ");
        }
    }
}
```

Есть такой код загрузки файлов. На входи приходит файл со списком файлов, путь, куда сохранять и количество потоков, для загрузки этих файлов. Я не совсем понимаю, как должна происходить загрузка через потоки.

```
protected void download(List<File> files, String path, String nThreads) {
        for (File file : files) {
            ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Integer.parseInt(nThreads));
            pool.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new Downloader(file.getUrl(), path, file.getName()).startDownload();
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    System.out.println(" ============================== ");
                }

            });
        }
    }
```

Я пробовал такой код, но работал только один поток.

Comment: вы создаете на каждый файл по пулу потоков, у вас должен быть один пул, в который вы будете сбрасывать задания по всем файлам

Comment: @etki не совсем понял, можно поподробнее

Comment: У вас ExecutorService создается внутри цикла, в результате на каждой итерации создается еще один ExecutorService (в то время как реально нужен только один), поэтому его создание стоит вынести из цикла. Это скорее всего не имеет прямого отношения к вашим проблемам (даже в такой ситуации работа должна происходить параллельно), но, тем не менее, является не очень корректным кодом.

Answer (score 0):

Вот этот код начал работать, однако, если убрать join, то перестаёт скачивать. В чём проблема может быть?
Фикс был в том, что пропустил = в строке

```
if(countTreads + threads.length <= files.size()) {
```

---

```
public class LoaderBean {


        protected void download(List<File> files, String path, String nThreads) throws InterruptedException {

            int countTreads = 0;
            int n = Integer.parseInt(nThreads);

            while(countTreads < files.size()) {
                Thread[] threads = new Thread[Integer.parseInt(nThreads)];

                for (int j = 0; j < n && j + countTreads != files.size(); ++j) {
                    threads[j] = new Thread(new MyThread(files.get(countTreads + j), path),
                            String.format("Thread %d", j));
                }

                if(countTreads + threads.length <= files.size()) {
                    countTreads = countTreads + threads.length;
                }
                startThreads(threads);
            }
        }

        private static void startThreads(Thread[] threads) throws InterruptedException {
            for (Thread thread : threads) {
                if(thread == null){
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                thread.start();
                //thread.join();
            }

        }
    }

    class MyThread implements Runnable {

        private String path;
        private File file;

        MyThread(File file, String path){
            this.path = path;
            this.file = file;
        }

        public  void run() {
            new Downloader(file.getUrl(), path, file.getName()).startDownload();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println(" ============================== ");
        }

    }
```